# Two firefox browser windows open in my selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am using a firefox driver and I notice that because I initialize a new instance of the firefox Driver, I have two fireFox windows open when my test runs. Is there a correct way in terms of initialising the driver as I may be wrong but I am guessing I shouldn't be writing `WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();` in two locations and somehow write it within one location only and call on it?

Page 1:

```
public class waitMethods extends PageObject {

    WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public void waitForElementToBeDisplayed(By element){
        try {
            WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 30);
            webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(element));
            System.out.println(element + " is displayed correctly");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail();
            System.out.println(element + " is not displayed");

        }
    }
```

Page 2:

```
public class WebPageMethods extends PageObject {

    WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();


    public void navigateToAuth0WebPage(){
        webDriver.get("https://www.test.com");
    }
```

Comment: Yes. Create the driver once and pass it along to all the page classes.

Comment: Make WebDriver public so you can use it's instance in all classes in package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example, how to inherit from WebDriver:

WebDriver setup class:

```
package brucey;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class WebDriverSetup {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\selenium-tests\\FF_driver_0_23\\geckodriver.exe";
    public static WebDriver startFF() {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
        FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
        options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
    }

    public static void shutdownFF() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Class containing methods used by driver:

```
package brucey;

import java.util.List;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class WebDriverBase extends WebDriverSetup {

    @BeforeClass public static void setUpClass() {
        startFF();
    }

    @Before public void setUp() {}

    @After public void tearDown() {}

    @AfterClass public static void tearDownClass() {
        shutdownFF();
    }

    public WebDriverWait waitSec(WebDriver driver, int sec) {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);
    } 

    public WebElement byId(String id) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
        return element;
    }   

    public WebElement byXpath(String xpath) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        return element;
    } 

    public WebElement byText(String text) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText(text));
        return element;
    }   

    public WebElement clickableByXpath(String xpath, int sec) {
           WebElement element = waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
           return element;
    }  

    public WebElement clickableByName(String name, int sec) {
           WebElement element = waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name(name)));
           return element;
    }    

    public WebElement visibleByXpath(String xpath, int sec) {
           WebElement element = waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
           return element;
    }   

    public WebElement visibleById(String id, int sec) {
       WebElement element = waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));
       return element;
    }   

    public List<WebElement> byXpaths(String xpath) {
           List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
           return elements;
    }   

    public void atr2beByXpath(int sec, String xpath, String atr, String val) {
        waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(By.xpath(xpath), atr, val));    
    }

    public void atrNot2beByXpath(int sec, String xpath, String atr, String val) {
        waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(By.xpath(xpath), atr, val)));
    }

    public void elements2beMoreByXpath(String xpath, int sec, int amount) {
        waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.xpath(xpath), amount));
    }

    public void elements2beByXpath(String xpath, int sec, int amount) {
        waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.xpath(xpath), amount));
    }

    public void tryUrl2be(int sec, String url) {
        try {waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe(url));
      } catch (TimeoutException e) {}
    }
    public void tryUrl2contain(int sec, String string) {
        try {waitSec(driver, sec).until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains(string));
      } catch (TimeoutException e) {}
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
package brucey;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

public class TestExample extends WebDriverBase {

    @Test
    public void testExample() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        waitSec(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(byId("some WebElement's ID")));
        // ...
    }
}
```